# Prediction based on new data in the tsDyn package

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I decided to use the tsDyn package to build the model and precision the values. The argument for this package (I previously worked with urca, vars) was the ability to make predictions based on new data.
My code looks like this:

```
start_n = 1548
delta_n = 300
pred_n = 24
k = 31

time_series <- zestaw[start_n:(start_n + delta_n-1),c("Osad.ilosc", "Biogaz.ilosc", "Sc.surowe")]

> time_series
# A tibble: 300 × 3
   Osad.ilosc Biogaz.ilosc Sc.surowe
        <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
 1       46.2        1204.     8370 
 2       46.2        1218.     8582.
 3       45.5        1202.     8967 
 4       45.8        1220      8024.
 5       45.8        1262.     7501 
 6       46.2        1200      7476.
 7       45.8        1170.     7482 
 8       45.8        1160.     7498.
 9       46.5        1190.     7494.
10       45.8        1230.     7484

# forecast
linevarf_diff.head <- predict(linevare_diff, n.ahead = pred_n) 
linevarf_diff.head
 
# forecast with newdata 
time_series.pred <- zestaw[(start_n + delta_n):(start_n + delta_n + k) ,
                             c("Osad.ilosc", "Biogaz.ilosc", "Sc.surowe")]
    
linevarf_diff.pred <- predict(linevare_diff, newdata = time_series.pred, n.ahead = pred_n) 
linevarf_diff.pred
```

[image]

I achieve predictions with satisfactory accuracy, especially when using new data. My question is why two time series (Osad.ilosc  and Sc.surowe) are also forecasted. What's more - the new data must cover all three time series (including Biogaz.ilosc, i.e. the time series that is subject to prediction).
I would like to better understand how this procedure works?